# Can we use notification API to send out messages our customers?

Tags: facebook, notifications

We would like develop a Facebook App to send notifications to our own customers. We would like send private messages to customers about their transactions in our core systems. Is notification the right approach?  Also, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

In general, yes.  Facebook has a notification API for an app to send a notification to a user.  There are some limitations, so I'd suggest looking at the documentation to understand if what it can do, and if its capabilities match what you want the app to do:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-notifications/